# how do I find all the times a program was installed?

Tags: command-prompt

I am willing to use PowerShell or Command Prompt:

I installed a program and I need to find out exactly when I installed it. I installed it twice and I want to find the first time I installed it.
Time meaning the date.

Comment: If you're not getting answers here, you may want to try posting on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstalled it, it should have wiped its existence from storage, therefore Windows should have no record of when you installed it (unless it created a restore point).